# Background issue

Tags: css, background

I am trying to make a background color, but all I got is a coloured rectangle above the footer.

Live example: http://solutionsmvo.nazwa.pl/test/

```
    body, html {
        font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        width: 100%; height: 100%;
        background-color: #582c2c;
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please provide a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) of your web page in order to be able to edit your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
body, html {
        font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        width: 100%; height: 100%;
        background-color: #582c2c !important;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `Bootstrap.min.css` is included below your `style.css` which results in overwriting your `background-color: #582c2c;`

Sequence of CSS inclusion should be as follows.

```
<link href="bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="style.css">
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because there is background-color property on body in Bootstrap.min.css, where background-color on body is #fff, so remove that line from Bootstrap.min.css...